# styling tabbar with css

Tags: html, css, tabs

I want to have a tabs like image below, but I don't have any idea to make it.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the tab into a png image. Here is one I did really quick. I have a border on the top and no border on the bottom so it will overlay the existing border making appear as it curves up

[image: Tab]

Then combine it with some styling to get your result

```css
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  
  border: 1px solid #d5d1d1;
}

.tabs {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #F4C949;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  text-align: right;
}

.tab {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab:focus {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ecy.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tab-content {
  height: 175px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab tab-active" tabindex="0">
      Tab 1
    </div>
    <div class="tab" tabindex="0">
      Tab 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    Click tab to get the effect
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a good trick, but what about border?

Comment: @BeHappy, Updated my answer

Comment: I'll check it and will tell you the result. tnx

Comment: Works great but I should create my own image because It is small for longer tab name.tnx

Comment: and there is also one problem, I want to have border around content div but when I set border property it looks like ugly, Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: @BeHappy, See my edit. I'm not entirely sure how you want the border, but you best option would be to add another `<div>` for the content and add the border to that. I did that with `.tab-content`

Comment: If you look my image in question border is continuous from left and right and border-bottom of tabs are same as border-top of content.

Comment: @BeHappy, check now, I tried to match everything from your picture. I didn't see the border on the content at the start.

Comment: it is amazing, tnx.